# Finding all different characters in an unknown language and lexicographical relation between them

Tags: algorithm

I have a dictionary in an unknown language. I have to find all the characters of this unknown language and lexicographical relation between them. What can be the most efficient way to do this ?

Note : 
1. There might be characters starting by which there is no word present in dictionary 
2. You can't assume that the ascii value of characters will be in sorted order 
3. There might be some characters among which you can't find any relation

e.g.

assume that someone don't know english and our dictionary is:

```
B
GA
GAS
GBS
GK
SG
```

Then the solution will be:

```
 A < B < G < S
 A < B < K
```

Comment: Is this a hypothetical situation, or is this a real language that somebody else might know? Could you give an example?

Comment: I don't think it will create any difference because the one who has to solve the problem doesn't know that language and he has to figure out a way to find the same (also you can't assume that the ascii value of characters will be sorted)

Comment: I have added an example to clarify the question

Comment: That example makes the assumption that `S` is less than `A`, `B` and `G`, but I don't see how that can be deduced. Also, `K` might very well be: `B < K < G`, the only thing you know of `K` is that it's less than `A` and `B`: `A < B < K`. The only things that can be deduced are: `A < B < G` and `A < B < K`, and `S` can go anywhere.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "There might be characters starting by which there is no word present in dictionary"?

Comment: @BartKiers my bad...missed one input..I have updated the example

Comment: @Bryan Like in above example...'A' is a character in this language but there is no word that begin with 'A'

Comment: This is basically the problem UVa 200, so you should be able to search for that for help.

Comment: @Nabb Thanks...will search for better solution using that reference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you linear solution. O(|all strings in dictionary| + |alphabet|). |s| - length of s

1. Make graph G(V,E). V - characters in alphabet, E = {v1, v2} where v1 less than v2.
2. Scan dictionary, compare 2 sequence words and add relationship information to graph.
3. Use [topological sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting) to get characters in the correct order. Complexity - O(|V|) = O(|alphabet|)

Comment: I was also thinking of topological sort. But the step "Scan dictionary, compare 2 sequence words and add relationship information to graph" ...won't this be too expensive ?? Because a relationship info can exist both vertically and horizontally so this will roughly take (n^2 * m^2) time where n is total no. of words and m is length of each word.

Comment: @r15habh, you need compare only i-th and (i+1)-th word. So, its O(N*M)

Comment: You are right, I was doing some unnecessary comparisons in a test case